# Show that there is a number $a \in (0,1]$ such that $U = [0,a) \bigcup W.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-explanation, connectedness

Let $U \subseteq I$ be an open set (but not all of $I$), and assume that $0 \in U.$ 
Show that there is a number $a \in (0,1]$ such that $U = [0,a) \bigcup W,$ where $W$ is also open in $I$ and $W \bigcap [0,a) = \emptyset.$

**My trial:**

I know that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of disjoint open intervals. I also know that we have 3 types of intervals an interval that is totally outside the interval $[0,1]$ from left, an interval that extends before and after $0$ by a small number say $\frac{-1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n \geq 1$ and a third interval that $(\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ but I do not know how to choose $a$ and $W$ in all these cases. I also know that a space $X$ is connected if the only separations of $X$ are the trivial ones(I am not sure how this may help here). Could anyone help me formulate a rigorous proof for this please?

Comment: What exactly is $I$?

Comment: @blat the unit interval

Answer (score 3):

Since $U$ is open and $0 \in U$ there exists $t>0$ such that $[0,t) \subseteq U$. Let $a=\sup \{t: [0,t) \subseteq U\}$. Let $W=(a,1]\cap U$. Can you verify that this satisfies the requirements?

[You will have to show that $a \notin U$. Prove this by contradiction].

Comment: No I can not .... I am not understanding your solution .... could you provide details please?

Comment: If $a \in U$ then $[0,a+\epsilon) \subseteq U$ for some $\epsilon >0$  because $U$ is open. So this would lead to a contradiction to the definition of $a$ as  a supremum. @Secretly

Comment: Can I use the subspace topology definition in the solution?

Comment: Yes. $W$ is open in $[0,1]$ by the definition of subspace topology.